# Problema ao alterar caracteres de uma matriz

Tags: c++, c++14

Eu estou com um problema onde dada uma matriz 10x10, a mesma tem que ser preenchida com caracteres asterisco e o 't'. Nessa matriz, APENAS os caracteres com as coordenadas que possuem 't' e que são vizinhas das coordenadas com caracteres contendo asterisco tem que ser substituídas pelo caractere 'p', conforme a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que eu desenvolvi consegue fazer a substituição, mas ele tem um problema: ele converte todos os 't' que estão localizados na extremidade esquerda e direita da matriz. Segue o código abaixo:

```
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  char matriz[10][10];

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
      cin >> matriz[i][j];
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
      if(matriz[i][j] == 't')
      {
        if( 
           matriz[i-1][j] == '*' || 
           matriz[i+1][j] == '*' || 
           matriz[i][j-1] == '*' || 
           matriz[i][j+1] == '*')
          {
            matriz[i][j] = 'p';
          }
      }
    }
  }

  cout << endl;

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
      cout << matriz[i][j]<< " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Eu montei uma matriz que mostra o problema:

```
ENTRADA:
* * * t t t * * * *
* * t t t t * * * *
* t t t t t t * * *
* * * * t t t t t t
* * * * * t t t t t
* * * * * t t t * t
* * * * t t t t * *
t t t t t t t t t *
t t t t t t t t * *
t t t t t * * * * *
```

```
SAÍDA:
* * * p t p * * * * 
* * p t t p * * * * 
* p p p t t p * * * 
* * * * p t t p p p 
* * * * * p t t p p 
* * * * * p t p * p 
* * * * p t t p * * 
p p p p t t t t p * 
p t t t t p p p * * 
p t t t p * * * * *
```

Como podem ver, o 't' na coordenada 4x9 e 8x0 também muda, o que é errado.

Comment: Possivelmente isso ocorre por que há um estouro de indice da matrix. Se por exemplo o progama está analisando a ```linha [8,0]```, a condicao ```matriz[i][j-1]``` procura por uma posicao que nao existe no caso ```j-1```, que é ```j = -1```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem um estouro de indices nas estremidades da sua matriz.
Na linha `[8,0]`, a condicao `matriz[i][j-1]` procura por uma posicao que nao existe no caso `j-1`, onde `j = -1`, isso ocorre em todas as linhas da coluna 0. Tambem ocorre esse estouro na extremidade da direita na coluna 9, onde o calculo  `j + 1`, resulta em `j = 10` e esse indice nao existe na matriz.

Para as linhas tambem ocorre o mesmo nas extremidades. Para solucionar faça uma verificação para cada extremidade.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  char matriz[10][10] ={{'*','*','*','t','t','t','*','*','*','*'},
                        {'*','*','t','t','t','t','*','*','*','*'},
                        {'*','t','t','t','t','t','t','*','*','*'},
                        {'*','*','*','*','t','t','t','t','t','t'},
                        {'*','*','*','*','*','t','t','t','t','t'},
                        {'*','*','*','*','*','t','t','t','*','t'},
                        {'*','*','*','*','t','t','t','t','*','*'},
                        {'t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','*'},
                        {'t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','*','*'},
                        {'t','t','t','t','t','*','*','*','*','*'}};

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
      cout << matriz[i][j]<< " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  cout << endl;
  cout << endl;
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {

      if( (matriz[i][j] == 't') && (matriz[i+1][j] == '*') && (i + 1) < 10 )
      {
        matriz[i][j] = 'p';
      }

      else if( (matriz[i][j] == 't') && (matriz[i-1][j] == '*') && (i -  1) >= 0 )
      {
        matriz[i][j] = 'p';
      }

      else if((matriz[i][j] == 't') && ((j +  1) < 10) && matriz[i][j + 1] == '*')
      {
        matriz[i][j] = 'p';
      }

      else if((matriz[i][j] == 't') && ((j -  1) >= 0) && matriz[i][j - 1] == '*')
      {
        matriz[i][j] = 'p';
      }    
    }  
  }


  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
      cout << matriz[i][j]<< " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Breno. Era isso mesmo!! Me ajudou muito